# Scraping More than rendered Data with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping apps names from Google Play Store and for each URL as input I get only 60apps (because the website rendered 60apps if the user doesn't scroll down). How is it working and how can I scrape all the apps from a page using BeautifulSoup and/or Selenium ?

Thank you

Here is my code :

```
urls = []

urls.extend(["https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/NEWS_AND_MAGAZINES/collection/topselling_paid"])

for i in urls:
    response = get(i)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    app_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="card no-rationale square-cover apps small")
    file = open("./InputFiles/applications.txt","w+")
    for i in range(0, len(app_container)):
        #print(app_container[i].div['data-docid'])
        file.write(app_container[i].div['data-docid'] + "\n")

    file.close()
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('./InputFiles/applications.txt'))
print("Applications : " + str(num_lines) )
```

Comment: If the +60 apps are rendered with JS, you're going to need something to render that JS. Requests won't do it

Comment: SuperStew, that's not true...you could figure out the XHR's sent from the JS when scrolling, and send those from Requests.  Not trivial, but certainly doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case You need to use `Selenium` . I try it for you an get the all apps . I will try to explain hope will understand.

Using `Selenium` is more powerful than other Python function .I used ChromeDriver so If you don't install yet You can install it in

> http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path=r'This part is your Driver path')
driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/NEWS_AND_MAGAZINES/collection/topselling_paid')

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") ## Scroll to bottom of page with using driver
sleep(5) ## Give a delay for allow to page scroll . If we dont program will already take 60 element without letting scroll
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='card-content id-track-click id-track-impression']") ## Declare which class

for a in x:
  print a.text
driver.close()
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
1. Pocket Casts
Podcast Media LLC
₺24,99
2. Broadcastify Police Scanner Pro
RadioReference.com LLC
₺18,99
3. Relay for reddit (Pro)
DBrady
₺8,00
4. Sync for reddit (Pro)
Red Apps LTD
₺15,00
5. reddit is fun golden platinum (unofficial)
TalkLittle
₺9,99
... **UP TO 75**
```

Note :

> Dont mind the money. Its my countr currency so It will change in yours.

**UPDATE ACCORDİNG TO YOUR COMMENT:**

The same data-docid is also in span tag.You can get it with using `get_attribute` . Just add below codes into your project.

```
y = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[class=preview-overlay-container]")

for b in y :
   print b.get_attribute('data-docid')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts
com.radioreference.broadcastifyPro
reddit.news
com.laurencedawson.reddit_sync.pro
com.andrewshu.android.redditdonation
com.finazzi.distquakenoads
com.twitpane.premium
org.fivefilters.kindleit
.... UP TO 75
```

Comment: Cool Thank you, last question, how can I get the data-docid="com.codified.hipyard"  attribute and not all the div or the app name?

Comment: I answered your question in last part . You can check it @userHG

Comment: Enjoy your coding :) @userHG